# Detect when Outlook Today View is open

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have created an addin using VSTO. I'm trying to determine when Outlook is opened or switched to the Today screen. I need to disable parts of the addin ribbon buttons when the Today view is displayed. Is there a property that I can check to determine if the Outlook Today screen is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid folders with the web view, check if the `MAPIFolder.WebViewOn` property is true (where `MAPIFolder` comes from Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder).

If you are really after the top level folder, read the entry id of the current folder (`Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID`) and compare it to that of the top level folder (`Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Store.GetRootFolder().EntryID`) using `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`